# Google Chrome - Auto log-off from sites

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, automatic-logon

I use Google Crome, everytime I close the browser or Shutdown my system and open the browser again, I am automatically logged off from all my accounts - GMail, Facebook, Yahoo but not from the Stack Exchange Websites. I want Google Crome to not log me out of any of the websites at all. How can I make that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com) for password management. When you save new password, check `Auto Login` option.
[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you register on Lastpass?

Comment: Yes, I have registered. I have the setting as said by you.

Comment: Even my Last Pass account logs off each time I close Crome or Shut Down the Laptop.

Comment: Yes, it will log off, because of security concern. But if you wish you can check remember password when logging in. But I strongly discourage you to do so.

Comment: but my question is how to not get logged off from GMail, facebook everytime I close Crome. It's my personal laptop - no one else uses it; if at all any one uses it throught the guest account.

Comment: Updated. Anyway, you just check `Remember Me` option and enable cookies; cookies are enabled by default on any browser. I couldn't understand, why are you facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to

Settings -> Under the hood -> Select `Allow local data to be set` in cookies

Uncheck the 2 checkboxes below this setting

allow Javascript (from same page)

Basically, use these settings : [image]

Also, when logging into sites, make sure you select the `remember me` option

Comment: I already have these setting on.

Comment: Try using the remember me option as well (and just clear **EVERYTHING** once. Maybe you have corrupted cookies)

Comment: okay, but what should I do for the websites that do not have "Remember me" thing at all? - It's not available in the Wiki Service Login page that I use.

Comment: If the website doesn't have an option to remember your session, LastPass is probably the best alternative.